# Restassured "OR" condition

Tags: rest-assured

I have REST for finding users by name, which for some search term returns users that has that term in first name or last name.

```
GET /search/joe
```

returns json array:

```
[
  {"id": 1, "firstName": "Joe", "lastName": "Doe"},
  {"id": 2, "firstName": "Alex", "lastName": "Joelson"}
]
```

How to test this REST with restassured and verify that given search term is contained in either first or last name of every row, case insensitive?

```
given()
  .when()
    .get("/user/search")
  .then()
    .statusCode(200)
    .body(?)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a `User` object:

```
Response response = given().when().get("/user/search");
response.then().statusCode(200);

JSONArray users = new JSONArray(response.asString());
for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(i);
  String firstName = user.getString("firstName").toLowercase();
  String lastName = user.getString("lastName").toLowercase();

  Assert.assertTrue(firstName.contains("joe") || lastName.contains("joe"));
}
```

If you have a `User` object, look into using Jackson or JsonPath to make the validation simpler. You can also look into using Hamcrest to do the validations.